# linq query close my wpf application

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have a wpf application. when I run it it close. I debugged it and I found that this linq query close it(I don't know why!)

```
TodayCards = cards.Where(i => (i.NextTime.Day == DateTime.Now.Day && i.NextTime.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && i.NextTime.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)).Select(i => i).ToList();
```

I also tried

```
TodayCards = cards.Where(i => (i.NextTime.Day == DateTime.Now.Day && i.NextTime.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && i.NextTime.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)).ToList();
```

but it closed it both situations.

Comment: is there an exception? if so, can you post it?

Comment: @SynerCoder there is no exception. Just program close. It was hard to find the problem but I found out after running this line program close

Comment: This would be clearer: `cards.Where(c => c.NextTime.Date == DateTime.Today).ToList()`

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: you can put a try-catch block around that line to catch the exception.

Comment: @James: In WPF applications exceptions in UI handlers silently kill your application without displaying any exception dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `NextTime` is `null` on at least one card or `cards` itself is `null`.

Comment: No. `cards` was null and I'm going to debug it!

Answer (score 1):

I found out why!
`cards` was null and it close my application. I put this code before my linq query:

```
        foreach (var item in cards)
        {
            if (item.NextTime == null)
            {
                int a = 0;
            }
        }
```

to find if there is any null next time but it closes before run and I found out the problem is `card`. I can't still say why it close the app without any exceptions but the problem resolved!