# Object serializing/deserializing doesn't work

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have an extension method for `System.Object` to serialize and deserialize objects using `Json.Net`. this is my Extension methods:

```
public static void SaveToFile(this object data, string FileName)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FileName))
    {
        string encode = WpfApplication.Helper.Encrypt(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
        writer.Write(encode);
        writer.Close();
    }
}

public static void LoadFromFile<t>(this object data, string FileName)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileName))
    {

        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<t>(WpfApplication.Helper.Decrypt(reader.ReadToEnd()));
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

and It's the class that I want to deserialize:

```
public class CardPack
{
    #region Properties
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private List<FlashCard> cards;

    public List<FlashCard> Cards
    {
        get { return cards; }
        set { cards = value; }
    }

    private bool registered;
    public bool Registered
    {
        get { return registered; }
        set { registered = value; }
    }

    private int currentCardIndex;

    public int CurrentCardIndex
    {
        get { return currentCardIndex; }
        set { currentCardIndex = value; }
    }

    public string RegisterKey { get; set; }

    public string ViewName { get; set; }

    public List<FlashCard> TodayCards { get; set; }
    #endregion
    ~CardPack()
    {
        foreach (FlashCard card in cards)
        {
            card.Check();
        }
        currentCardIndex = 0;
        TodayCards = null;
        this.SaveToFile(string.Format(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Split(@"file:\\")[1] + @"\Packs\{0}.json", name));
    }
```

but whenever I deserialize the class `cards` is empty and I don't know how to resolve the problem. Can anybody help me?

**Update**
I find the error when I had this code:

```
public CardPack(string Name)
    {
        this.name = Name;
        this.LoadFromFile<CardPack>(string.Format(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Split(@"file:\\")[1] + @"\Packs\{0}.json", name));
        foreach (var item in cards)
        {
            if (item.NextTime == null)
            {
                int a = 0;
            }
        }
        TodayCards = cards.Where(c => c.NextTime.Date == DateTime.Today).ToList();
    }
```

because the application closed when it tries to run `foreach (var item in cards)`!
I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509607/linq-query-close-my-wpf-application) and found out that `cards` is empty!

**update2** I serialized the `CardPack` object with a little different structure. in previous structure `Cards` property was read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<t>(WpfApplication.Helper.Decrypt(reader.ReadToEnd()));` in extension method doesn't change to 'data' class then `Cards` in `CardPack` is always null. I'll ask a question to find out why I cant set the class from it's extension method later.